# Is it possible to do calculations with 2 different worksheets in Minitab?

Tags: minitab

The problem I am having is that I have 2 extremely large sets of data in two different worksheets. Their parameters match up exactly (I unstacked the data using identical parameters). The data is too large to fit in one Minitab worksheet so I want to divide the two different worksheets. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at Minitab and we saw this question come through the @statsqa Twitter feed. I ran your question by our technical support group. Here was their response: There is no way to perform a calculation that references 2 different worksheets, which is I believe what they are looking for.

We've passed this item along to our feedback team for consideration in a future release of Minitab. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing this up. I'm sure its a very rare problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Minitab in decades and won't be able to answer beyond this but for the sake of any expert Minitab users on the forum, I point out that this seems very confused. Your title and your question at different points seem to support opposite interpretations:

A. You have two worksheets already.

A'. You want to divide a worksheet into two worksheets.

B. You want to work with different worksheets separately. [Surely you can if they fit into memory...]

B'. You want to work with different worksheets together in some way.

Comment: Let me try to clarify. I had one large worksheet of data. I tried to unstack 2 large columns of data as per 2 indeces. When I tried to unstack the two columns together and put them in one worksheet, Minitab told me that this was not possible. I could, however, unstack the two columns seperately into different worksheets. What I want to know now is if I can do calculations between those two worksheets. I apoligize for any ambiguity.

Comment: Sounds like my B'. Either way, you depend on Minitab experts now. I don't know that there are many left any more.

Comment: OK Thanks for your help! I was told to post this in stackexchange by a mod so I'll give you the question answered.